# Good Photographs with Moto G2 Camera

Tags: lens, autofocus, focus, camera-settings, megapixels

I have got a MOTO G2 Mobile with 8MP front camera, usually i get best shot from my phone but is there any way so that i can capture best pictures with a mobile camera everytime?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my knowledge phone cameras can't offer you such dynamic range as it can be from (for example) mirrorless or DSLR. The reason for this is much smaller sensor. Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor_format) for some reference of the sizes.

Also many (probably all) photos of professional level are tuned and corrected in postprocessing. And usually this work is done with RAW files (which offer a lot of advantages). And not so much phones can provide RAW output so you are limited in this direction too.

P.S. For getting best possible photo with phone you should avoid shooting high contrast scenes and always try (where is applicable) to make exposure as much as possible right. Also you can avoid to shoot gradient colours as phones (usually) do not reproduce gradient very well.